# get duplicate "base" URLs with mySQL

Tags: mysql

I can't quite seem to figure this out, and hoping someone can help. I was trying something like this, but doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM testtable 
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(urlTest,'/',3) 
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Here is a (simplified) table structure with what I am using:

```
CREATE TABLE `testtable` (
  `field1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `field2` datetime NOT NULL,
  `urlTest` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `testtable` (`field1`, `field2`, `urlTest`) VALUES
(2, '2010-01-01', 'http://test1.com/somethingelse.php?id=1'),
(5, '2010-01-01', 'http://test1.com/'),
(6, '2012-02-02', 'http://test1.com/newscript/something'),
(7, '2013-02-02', 'http://test2.com/newscript/something'),
(8, '2014-02-02', 'http://test3.com/newscript/something'),
(9, '2015-02-02', 'http://test3.com/');

ALTER TABLE `testtable`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`field1`);
```

The output I want to get is to return any "base" urls that are identical with an 'identical' date, that I can manually inspect.

In other words, although "test1.com/somethingelse.php?id=1" and "test1.com" are "unique" url entries, the "base" url (i.e., "test1.com") is identical/a duplicate (because the dates -> 2010-01-01 <- are also identical). However, test1.com/newscript/something would *not* count as a 'duplicate' - because although the 'base' url is the same - it has a 'unique' date to the rest of the 'test1.com' urls (i.e., "2012-02-02")

So the output I'd like to get is:

```
2, 2010-01-01, 'http://test1.com/somethingelse.php?id=1'
5, 2010-01-01, 'http://test1.com/'
```

(because only test1.com has the same "base" unique URL (test1.com) as well as has the same timestamp. "test3.com" - while the same "base" url - since the actual timestamps are different, would be considered 'unique' urls)

How would I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting all fields makes no sense - server will output one RANDOM field value from all values in the group. Use

```
SELECT testtable.*
FROM testtable
JOIN ( SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(urlTest,'/',3) AS domain,
              field2
       FROM testtable 
       GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(urlTest,'/',3), field2 
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) domains
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(testtable.urlTest,'/',3) = domains.domain
  AND testtable.field2 = domains.field2
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2fd4d707217f15ea94f6b08b90957c7f)

Comment: wow! i'm impressed! that is very cool, thanks very much for your help! I've been trying to figure it out for quite some time now! thanks very much! :D

Comment: follow-up question (now that this works great!) and I can see the 'duplicate' urls... something I didn't anticipate is "some" base urls require a 'longer' substring_index, - so 
what would be the best way of doing that?

Comment: i.e, say I have "test1.com", "test2.com" and "test3.com",
and I want to 'individually' add specific domain bases, but specify how many slashes there should be for each? i.e.,

Comment: shoot - sorry, I keep typing and it keeps ending the comment. anyways, kind of like:
http://www.test1.com/random
http://www.test1.com/otheroutput 
(so test1.com is "3" slashes)
http://www.test2.com/base/newrandom
http://www.test2.com/base/otheritem
(so "4" slashes, because up until "/base/" everything is identical)
then say:
http://www.test3.com/base/newrandom/variablending001
http://www.test3.com/base/newrandom/variablending002
http://www.test3.com/base/newrandom/variablending003
(so '3' variable endings in this case)? so "5" slashes...

or... it just occurred to me...

Comment: @user6262902 New task is relative slightly. I'd recommend to create new question, with new DDL+data scripts and desured output.

Comment: is there a way to do a "reverse" url - i.e., test if the 'endings' are different to the "first" slash - and then make sure everything preceding it is identical?

ie.., "test1.com/identical/same/something/NEWDIFFERENT and test1.com/identical/same/something/AGAINDIFFERENT" would see the "NEWDIFFERENT" and "AGAINDIFFERENT" - then verify that the preceding base URL was identical?

Comment: kk, thanks - will do & will post shortly, thanks very much for your help! you're awesome! :)

Comment: @user6262902 No problems. `slashes_amount = length(value) - length(replace(value, '/', ''))`

Comment: thanks! just posted the question here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/249819/get-base-urls-with-different-endings-after-the-last-slash